# How to run Selenium C# tests on real android device in browser?

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, specflow

I need to add the ability to my existing Specflow/C#/Selenium/NUnit project to run tests in a browser on a mobile phone without using emulation. Please can you point me to a useful guide so I can achieve this? I keep finding guides in Java or guides to do this via a business's services, it's so frustrating. I need to use Appium... maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As Selenium itself hasn't have the ability to communicate with mobile device directly, Yes you need to integrate tool such as Appium.

Appium internally use Selenium and have a another wrapper on top of it which have the ability to communicate with mobile devices or emulators

Some C# reference for Appium are as below:

**Important :**

https://www.diatomenterprises.com/testing-mobile-apps-with-specflow-and-appium/

https://applitools.com/tutorials/appium-web-csharp.html#analyze-your-test-results

**Others :**

https://www.automatetheplanet.com/getting-started-appium-android-csharp/

https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/ios-mobile-app-automation-testing-using-appium-and-c

Comment: You might also look into a SauceLabs account. They acquired TestObject so you can test across multiple real devices.